# Delegate prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can Method delegation ([delegate prototype](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/3-different-kinds-of-prototypal-inheritance-es6-edition-32d777fa16c9#.dovq087e4)) preserve memory resources?

Since method delegation preserve memory, is this one of the reason method delegation/prototype inheritance preferred over classical inheritance?

Comment: considering even ES3 allowed internal function recycling, the RAM savings of prototypes is greatly exaggerated. it's still not a bad pattern, but it's not nearly as dramatic a savings as one naively expects.

Comment: @dandavis Can you provide a link about this? I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: it's not widely covered. see the NOTE in 13.1.2  of [the es3 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) talking about SCOPE and function object reuse. i did some testing long ago and the measurements seemed to confirm the partial lack of savings between a factory and a constructor.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for that reference, but I don't think it is applicable to this discussion because an instance of a constructor function differs from its prototype in more than just it's internal [[scope]] property, which is what the spec uses as a litmus test for when two object can be represented by just one. I believe that the memory savings we're discussing are real and not optimized away.

Comment: @dandavis I just did a quick test to confirm and, it is true that your reading of that section of the spec. is not applicable here. The spec. says *"If objects O and P are joined, they compare as == and === to each other."* So, if you test a function *f* (for the test, *f* was just an empty function with nothing to taint it) against an instance *o* of *f* (`o == f` or `o===f`), you get false, thus the objects are not joined and the section in question doesn't apply.

Comment: @dandavis Lastly, the section starts with: *When two or more Function objects are joined...*. But, what we are discussing is a constructor function and an instance object, which is not two function objects. This section of the spec. is referring to literally having two functions that are identical in all public ways (and all internal except for [[scope]]). This would allow two identical *foo* functions with different scopes to be joined, but not *foo* and instances of *foo* or even `foo.prototype`

Comment: @dandavis Sorry for going on and on... But, one last thing if you test a simple empty function *f* against its prototype, you also get false. This is the most directly relevant scenario to what we are discussing here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: i just meant that factory methods (o.hit = hitme;) are not instantly _n_ times more footprinty than shared prototype methods. if you define a factory method in the factory, it probably can't be re-used. but if defined outside (like a proto), it's just another prop assignment... closure is set at compile time, `this` is set at call time, so recycling methods is easy.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure about your using the term "factory methods" here. Nonetheless, instance properties (regardless of whether they store objects, primitives or functions) must store that data per instance and so there *is* and instant memory cost to them.  Prototype properties have the same cost, but since only prototype is needed to serve all the instances, that cost is reduced.  The savings can easily be calculated (bytes of property value * instances vs. bytes of property value).

Comment: methods aren't attached to object instance properties, the cost of storage falls on the object, not the method. simply consider how many `alert()`s this needs: `[{a:alert},{a:alert}]`... hint : `.bind()` creates a new function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegating out methods via the prototype saves memory because that means you don't need multiple copies of the same function.

```
function A() {
  this.hello = function() {
    console.log('A new function is created in memory every time');
    console.log('an instance of A is created');
  };
}

function B() { }
B.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log('Only one function is created and every instance');
  console.log('of B shares this one function');
};
```

As for why it's better to use method delegation via the prototype than classical inheritance **in JavaScript**, that's because JavaScript does not actually support classical inheritance. Anything you see that mimics classical inheritance is exactly that: a mimicry.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that prototypical inheritance is preferred over classical inheritance, it's simply that JavaScript is not a compiled language and so, it needs a different approach.

By attaching methods (behaviors) to the prototype, they are stored once for all instances that use that prototype. If you were to attach them to the instances themselves, each instance would take up more memory just to store a behavior that is no different than any other instance.

This is why, typically, properties that store primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) are created as *instance properties*, because their values can differ from instance to instance (i.e. p1.name = "Scott", p2.name = "Mary"). But properties that store functions simulate methods (behavior) and the behavior to return a value (say a name) doesn't change from instance to instance.  So methods tend to be added to the prototype.

For example:

```js
    function Person(name){
    
       // This is an "instance property". Every time an instance
       // of Person is created, that instance will store a name property
       // in the object's memory. This type of property needs to be set up
       // like this because each Person can/will have a different name.
       this.name = name; 
    }
    
    // This method always does the same thing, regardless of
    // what instance it's dealing with, so it's better to store
    // it just one time on the object that all Person instances
    // will inherit from:
    Person.prototype.getName = function(){ return this.name; }


    // Both of these Person instances inherit from the same (one) Person
    // prototype. 
    var p1 = new Person("Scott");
    var p2 = new Person("Mary");
    
    // So while each instance reserves space to store a name:
    console.log(p1.name); // "Scott"
    console.log(p2.name); // "Mary"
    console.log(p1.hasOwnProperty("name"));  // true
    console.log(p2.hasOwnProperty("name"));  // true
    console.log(p1.hasOwnProperty("getName"));  // false
    console.log(p2.hasOwnProperty("getName"));  // false
    
    // Neither of those instances are storing the function for getName().
    // That is being stored just once in Person.prototype and p1 and p2
    // are inheriting that behavior:
    console.log(p1.getName()); // "Scott"
    console.log(p2.getName()); // "Mary"
    console.log(p1.hasOwnProperty("getName"));  // false
    console.log(p2.hasOwnProperty("getName"));  // false
    console.log(p1.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("getName"));  // true
```

Comment: In Classical inheritance (not in JavaScript), there isn't method delegation. It has sub classes and references to superclass. Which one is more efficient using method delegation or using classical inheritance?

Comment: @Yogesh There is no answer to that question. Classical inheritance works in pre-compiled environments, JavaScript is not pre-compiled. Apples and Oranges. In JavaScript, you don't have a choice - - Classes don't exist. In classical languages (i.e. Java, C#, etc.) you don't have a choice, prototypes don't exist.

Comment: If I were to choose type of inheritance (classical or prototype) for a language to implement, what factors to consider. is it pre-compiled environment or anything else?

Comment: @Yogesh Preference. Theoretically, you can make classical inheritance faster than prototype-based inheritance since you can make guarantees about runtime behavior during the compilation stage. Prototype-based inheritance allows for a more flexible runtime but sacrifices speed for it. Likewise, multiple dispatch works better in compiled languages because you don't have to perform argument count checks or type checks during runtime (assuming a strong type system).

Comment: @Yogesh The reality is that both systems work well. It just depends on how you want your language to behave. Do you prefer strongly-structured object hierarchies? Classical inheritance is the way to go. Do you want the ability to easily change object behavior at runtime? Prototype-based inheritance is better. You can create a language with classical inheritance but implement it using prototypes although it won't exactly be intuitive. You could implement prototypes in a classical language but it would require a lot of type casting and event delegation via a Reflection-like mechanism.